# Git: Local and Remote Repositories out of Sync

Tags: git, github, repository

I tried pushing my local Git repository to my remote one on GitHub using the GitHub GUI.

I got en error saying "TriangleTiles has been updated on https://github.com/j76goatboy/TriangleTiles.git since you last synced. You can try syncing again or run `git pull origin master && git push origin master` from the command line."

[image: Image of error message]

My local repository has the most recent changes and I want to push those changes onto the remote repository. I tried using the command line but it gave me a similar error.

How do I sync my local and remote repositories without losing my changes?

Comment: git pull --rebase origin master and then do git push origin. If you are *really* sure your local changes are the newest ones and only you are working on this repo then do git push origin master -f to force a push on the remote repo.

Comment: @user244255 prefer --force-with-lease instead of force push to prevent destroying history that you didn't noticed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if I've misunderstood but the error means there are changes on GitHub you don't have locally.

Commit your local changes, then do as the error says. Pull from GitHub, merge the changes and fix any merge conflicts (if auto merge doesn't work), then push back to GitHub.

Comment: Would pulling from GitHub replace the contents of my local repo with the online one, or would it only pull down the things that my local one is missing?

Comment: It would try to merge the remote files with your local, if it couldn't do it automatically (because both contain an edit to the same file/code), it would mark the files for you to do manually. Once it's merged, you commit the results, and push the commits back to the remote repository.

Comment: You could also first 'fetch' to see what changes prevent you to push and then decide if you want to rebase or merge...